# How can I make my audio file work when the timer reaches 00:00?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have my 25+5 Pomodoro clock almost finished but now i want it to play the audio file when the timer reaches 00:00 at the end of the session and break. I changed the audio file from WAV to mp3 and I think the <audio> shouldn't be the problem as well but no idea what could fix it.

here is the audio file:
[https://www.peter-weinberg.com/files/1014/8073/6015/BeepSound.wav]

```
const audio = document.getElementById('beep');

class App extends React.Component {
  
state = {
        breakCount: 1,
        sessionCount: 1,
        clockCount: 1 * 10,
        currentTimer: "Session",
        isPlaying: false,
        loop: undefined
        }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.loop = undefined;    
    }
  
    componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
    }
  
    handlePlayPause = () => {
  const {isPlaying} = this.state;
   
  if (isPlaying){
    clearInterval(this.loop);
   
    this.setState({
      isPlaying: false
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      isPlaying: true
    });
   
    this.loop = setInterval(() => {
      const { 
        clockCount, 
        currentTimer, 
        breakCount, 
        sessionCount 
      } = this.state;
       
      if(clockCount === 0){
        this.setState({
          currentTimer: (currentTimer === 'Session') ? 'Break' : 'Session',
          clockCount: (currentTimer === 'Session') ? (breakCount * 60): (sessionCount * 60)
        });
         
        //const audio = new Audio('/Users/diemervandenberg/Desktop/25+5 clock FCC/BeepSound.mp3');
        audio.play();
      } else {
        this.setState({
          clockCount: clockCount - 1
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

  
  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      breakCount: 5,
      sessionCount: 25,
      clockCount: 25 * 60,
      currentTimer: "Session",
      isPlaying: false,
     })
    clearInterval(this.loop);
    
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
  
    convertToTime(count) {
  let minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
  let seconds = count % 60;

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? ('0'+minutes) : minutes; 
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? ('0'+seconds) : seconds;

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

  
  handleLengthChange = (count, timerType) => {
    const { 
      sessionCount, 
      breakCount, 
      isPlaying, 
      currentTimer
    } = this.state;
    
    let newCount;
    
    if(timerType === 'session') {
      newCount = sessionCount + count;
    } else {
      newCount = breakCount + count;
    }
    
    if(newCount > 0 && newCount < 61 && !isPlaying) {
      this.setState({
        [`${timerType}Count`]: newCount
      });
      
      if(currentTimer.toLowerCase() === timerType) {
        this.setState({
          clockCount: newCount * 60
        })
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  
 // handleBreakIncrease = () => {
 //   const { breakCount } = this.state;
    
 //   if (breakCount < 60){
 //     this.setState({
 //       breakCount: breakCount + 1
 //     })
 //    }
 // }
  
 // handleBreakDecrease = () => {
 //   const { breakCount } = this.state;
 //   
 //   if (breakCount > 1) {
 //     this.setState({
 //       breakCount: breakCount - 1                  
 //      })
 //    }
 //  }
  
 //   handleSessionDecrease = () => {
 //    const { sessionCount } = this.state;
    
 //   if (sessionCount > 1) {
 //     this.setState({
 //       sessionCount: sessionCount - 1                  
 //     })
 //   }
 // }
  
 // handleSessionIncrease = () => {
 //  const { sessionCount } = this.state;
    
 //   if (sessionCount < 60){
 //     this.setState({
 //       sessionCount: sessionCount + 1
 //    })
//    }
//  }
  
  
    render() {
      const {
        breakCount, 
        sessionCount, 
        clockCount, 
        currentTimer,
        isPlaying
      } = this.state;
       
      const breakProps = {
        title: 'Break Length',
        count: breakCount,
        handleIncrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(1, 'break'),
        handleDecrease: () => this.handleLengthChange(-1, 'break')
      };
      
      const sessionProps = {
        title: 'Session Length',
        count: sessionCount,
        handleDecrease: () =>  this.handleLengthChange(-1, 'session'),
        handleIncrease: () =>  this.handleLengthChange(1, 'session')
      };
           
  return (
      <div>
        <div className="flex">
          <SetTimer {...breakProps} />
          <SetTimer {...sessionProps} />
        </div>
        
        <div className="clock-container">
          <h1 id="timer-label">{currentTimer}</h1>
          <span id="time-left">{this.convertToTime(clockCount)}</span>
        
          
          <div className="flex">
            <button id="start_stop" onClick={this.handlePlayPause}>
              <i className={`fas fa-${isPlaying ? 'pause': 'play'}`} />
            </button>
            <button id="reset" onClick={this.handleReset}>
              <i className="fas fa-sync" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
    
  const SetTimer = (props) => {
  const id = props.title.toLowerCase();
  
  return (
    <div className="timer-container">
      <h2 id={`${id}-label`}>
        {props.title} 
      </h2>
      <div className="flex actions-wrapper">
        <button id={`${id}-decrement`} onClick={props.handleDecrease}>
          <i className="fas fa-minus" />
        </button>
        
        <span id={`${id}-length`}>{props.count}</span>
        
        <button id={`${id}-increment`} onClick={props.handleIncrease}>
          <i className="fas fa-plus" />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

HTML:

```
<div id='app'></div>
<audio autoplay id="beep" preload="auto" src="/Users/(myname)/Desktop/25+5 clock FCC/BeepSound.mp3" />

<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');

*{
  box-size: border-box;
}

body{
  
  background-color: #006266;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.timer-container {
  margin: 20px ;
}
.timer-container h2{
  margin: 0;
}

.actions-wrapper button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.actions-wrapper span {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 50px;
}

.clock-container {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 30px ;
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

.clock-container span{
  font-size: 50px;
}

.clock-container h1{
  margin: 0;
}

.clock-container button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Checked to how to use <audio>, changed file type, checked with chatGPT, read through the code for a few times but didn't get error messages

Answer (score -1):

I checked your HTML portion of code. There is a error in it that you can notice here-
`<audio autoplay id="beep" preload="auto" src="/Users/(myname)/Desktop/25+5 clock FCC/BeepSound.mp3" />`
I noticed that in the opening tag you putted the forward slash symbol. The correct code will be-
`<audio autoplay id="beep" preload="auto" src="/Users/(myname)/Desktop/25+5 clock FCC/BeepSound.mp3">`